# JSON Object with Embedded array Save in Controller

Tags: arrays, json, grails, groovy

Not sure how to extract the array in JSON from controller.  I have a JSON Object that contains an order with an array of products.  The JSON is nested like this but for brevity I reduced the many fields I have.

```
{ "customerId": "23",   "customerName": "Johnson",
    "products":[
    {
        "productId": "1",
        "finalPrice": "1.00"
    },
    {
        "productId": "2",
        "finalPrice": "2.00"
    },
    {
        "productId": "3",
        "finalPrice": "3.00"
    }
]}
```

I then have a Controller code that needs to take this and parse it and save it into two tables... Orders and OrdersProducts.  This is what I have so far but its not right some how have to take input and for loop each item and save.

```
class OrdersController {
    def save = {
        def input = request.JSON

        def order = new Orders(input)
        order.save(flush:true)

        // Somehow I have to loop this for each item in array???
        def products = new OrdersProducts(input)
        products.ordersId = order.id

        products.save(flush:true)
        // ???????
    }   

}
```

**---------- MY SOLUTION ----------**

After taking answer from below and modifying it to suit my particular needs,(legacy database structure), this is what I did to manually insert each product:

OrdersController.groovy

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.converters.XML

class OrdersController {
    def save = {
        def i
        def input = request.JSON

        def order = new Orders(input)
        if (order.save(failOnError:true)) {
            for (def products: input.ordersProducts) {
                def prod = new OrdersProducts(products)
                prod.ordersId = order.id

                if (prod.save(failOnError:true)) {
                //      
                } else {
                    prod.errors.allErrors.each { println it }
                }
            }
        } else {
            order.errors.each { println it }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are 'Orders' and 'OrdersProducts' related? I'm guessing they are related as,

```
static hasMany = [ordersProducts: OrderProducts]
```

In this case, you can parse the string to JSON and then initialize the objects,

```
...
def j = grails.converters.JSON.parse(input)

def order = new Orders(j)
...

order.ordersProducts = j.products
```

Comment: Unfortunately its a legacy database and linked through two fields.  So I have to do this manually.

Comment: in your `Orders' class, you can associate with 'OrdersProduct' using the 'hasMany'. If this is not feasible, you can loop through, j.products.each { new OrderProducts(it) }

Comment: Still lost on how to loop through this, even your grails.converters.JSON.parse errors out with "No signature of method: static grails.converters.JSON.parse() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject".  Why is it with Grails I want to do something simple, its never simple.

Comment: just check that JSON refers to grails.converters.JSON ( import grails.converters.JSON )